# Codeigniter: MY_Model - How to access uploaded file from postman client

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, rest, my-model-jami

I cannot access files that are sent in postman client with the option `form-data` option selected in it. when I access the sent data `$this->put();` it prints the below array.

```
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundarycQlF0G13IAOGFUhL
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "file"; filename="screenshot_menu.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

�����Exif
)
```

I guess its in binary. I have to convert it to actual image file and move this image to a folder.

Answer (score -1):

this is the code for file upload in codeigniter

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
```

here in $data variable you would get details of the uploaded file